codecoverage with phpunit on netbeans cant find its log
I'm trying to get code-coverage running in netbeans with phpunit 11. My tests are running but I constantly get this output:
Full output can be found in Output window.
Coverage log not found!
Perhaps you need to add "whitelist" to your XML configuration?

My generated xml was just an empty phpunit tag and from the sparse information I found (the documentation in https://docs.phpunit.de/en/11.1/configuration.html does not even have the word "whitelist" I tried to botch this together:
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<phpunit colors="false" bootstrap="/../bootstrap.php">
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">_src/</directory>
        </include>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">vendor/</directory>
        </exclude>
    </source>
    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">_src/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <coverage>
        <report>
            <clover outputFile="clover.xml"/>
            <cobertura outputFile="cobertura.xml"/>
            <crap4j outputFile="crap4j.xml" threshold="50"/>
            <html outputDirectory="html-coverage" lowUpperBound="50"    highLowerBound="90"/>
            <php outputFile="coverage.php"/>
            <text outputFile="coverage.txt" showUncoveredFiles="false" showOnlySummary="true"/>
            <xml outputDirectory="xml-coverage"/>
        </report>
    </coverage>
</phpunit>

Still does not do any good. Coverage log not found! - yeah, where did it look? where did it expect it? What am I supposed to do? Can anyone tell me more?

In netbeans (version 23), go to menu "Window" > "Output". What does it say? Something like ?
XDEBUG_MODE=coverage (environment variable) or xdebug.mode=coverage (PHP configuration setting) has to be set ?

If that is the case, simply doing what the output suggests should be sufficient. You may want to

either start netbeans by setting the environment variable. Like this:
XDEBUG_MODE=coverage netbeans


or update your php configuration (php.ini at any suitable location on your system) to have xdebug.mode=coverage. If you already have xdebug.mode=debug, you could add coverage to it, like this
xdebug.mode=debug,coverage.
See: https://xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage#mode


